# JQuery - OnClick .show() a stack of divs in order with a 5ms delay between each

Tags: jquery, image, sequence

Looking to get a stack of divs that create an image sequence to play on `click`.

So, 50 divs stacked with `#img01` being the only image showing on page load (49 others are not showing via `display:none;` css)

I'm looking for a simple piece of code that executes on `click` of `#img01` - On `click` hide `#img01` and show `#img02`, then 5ms after that `hide` `#img02` and show `#img03`, and so on and so forth until it gets to `#img50`...ending up with a flipbook effect.

Hoping there's a simple way to do this in just a few lines of code instead of writing out a `function` with a `timeout` for each frame.

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery you can use setInterval().

```
var intervalId;
var images = [];
$('#img01').one('click', function(e){
  getImages();
  startInterval();
});

function startInterval(){
  intervalId = setInterval(function(){
    //here you can hide and show from the images array
  });
}

function getImages(){
  var img = $('body').find('img');
  $,each(img, function (i, e){
    if($.inArray($(e), images) > -1)
      images.push($(e));
  });
}
```

Its not testet, but i would do it something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (example with 10 elements):

```
$( function() {
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      $('#div' + i.toString()).fadeIn({duration: (100 * i)});
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      $('#div' + i.toString()).fadeOut({duration: (100 * i)});
  }
});
```

See it in action in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/443y8w32/4/)